# RequireJS - optimize to more than one file and load on demand

Tags: requirejs, js-amd

We have a large **single page** application with approximately 200 modules -

When we use the optimizer - we are ending up with all the modules in one file uglified etc.
Works beautifully.

But ours is a kind of a multi-tenant application where every user does not need all the 200 modules.

We can broadly divide the modules into 50 common modules, 100 modules which are required if user type is 'A' and 50 modules for user type 'B' etc.

Now if the user type is 'B' the downloaded one single optimized file contains 100 modules which are never used. Somehow if we can avoid those, the file size will be much less which would really increase the performance.

In short I am looking for this - We have groups of modules - optimize the group of modules into it's own file - download the corresponding file based on the user on demand.

Is it possible to do this kind of optimization with requireJS?

Thanks, J.

Answer (score 0):

You could build an base module with all the things you need to start the app and the  stuff most users will see. [From the docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html):

> The optimizer will only combine modules that are specified in arrays
>   of string literals that are passed to top-level require and define
>   calls, or the require('name') string literal calls in a simplified
>   CommonJS wrapping. So, it will not find modules that are loaded via a
>   variable name
>
> ...
>
> This behavior allows dynamic loading of modules even after optimization. 
>   You can always explicitly add modules that are not found via the
>   optimizer's static analysis by using the include option.

All modules that you dont want to have in there, have to be required like this in your modules:

```
define(["require"], function(require) {
        return function(b) {
            var lib = 'lib'
            var a =  require(lib);
            a.doSomething(b);
        }
    }
);
```

so they will be not part of your initial load but loaded when needed.

Comment: The modules which are part of my initial load are comibined into one file and there is only one HTTP request to load that file, but For the modules which are not part of my initial load, a separate HTTP request will go for each module, this is the part I am looking to optimize.

Comment: @luissquall Same here, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as though you'd be better off splitting your single page app into two single page apps sharing common code as described in the require docs [Optimizing a multi-page project](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#wholemultipage).

This will mean that for anything shared for user types A and B there ought to be one HTTP request and then for user type A or B another HTTP request with the modules specific to that module type.